# Enabling .swf files on Apache

Tags: linux, apache, actionscript, flash

I have no experience with swf files or actionscript prior to this. I updated mysql, apache, and php today on a linux server (SUSE 10). I've managed to get everything up and running correctly... except a few swf pages. I have a feeling it has to do with the configuration of apache as the pages worked prior to the updates I performed today, and now do not.

I found http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=211719 and http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/swf-flash-file-not-openning-from-linux-apache-server-pls-suggest-709567/ that all discussed my problem and I followed their changes.

My httpd.conf currently contains 
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf

also, LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so is in the httpd.conf.

In the mime.types, I have
application/x-shockwave-flash swf

Is this all that is necessary to enable swfs? I haven't downloaded any packages for them or anything. I feel like I must be missing something.

Does anyone have an idea why the .swf pages aren't loading properly? They somewhat appear to be "hanging". I don't know how actionscript/swfs work, but if I visit the main swf page, it somewhat loads. I fill in some information and press submit, and it gets "stuck" (cursor goes away if mousing over the page). Any help would be much appreciated. PM for a link to the site.

Comment: Any ideas would be incredibly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a link to the swf file itself you can determine if it's an Apache issue with serving up the swf or if that works fine then it may be how you have it embedded in the page.

Hitting the file directly via url should either download the swf to your computer or render it in the browser. If that works then it's not a config issue.